# Mokito, Mocking method behavior

Tags: java, android, mockito

I am fairly new to automated testing and I have been having some trouble with mocking a class with mockito. Basically what I am trying to do is make use of an interface that is being sent to a method, when this method (Request(Response)) is called I want mockito to intervene and call a method from the interface passing an object as a param (callback.OnSuccess(Obj)). Here is an example of what I mean, I will start off with my production code I have taken out everything that isnt needed:

ServerRequest class

```
public void Request(ResponseInterface callback){
 //The contents of this class isnt really important as I do not wish to use any of it
//but in general this makes a request to the server and if the request is a success then
Object obj = ProcessResponse(Response);
callback.OnSuccess(obj);
//otherwise
Object obj = ProcessResponse(Response);
callback.OnError(obj);
}
```

ResponseInterface

```
public interface ResponseInterface(){
void OnSuccess(Object resp);
void OnError(Object resp);
}
```

MainActivity

```
public void MakeRequest(){
ServerRequest.Request(new ResponseInterface(){
@Override
public void OnSuccess(Object objResponse){
 //do something to show user the request was successful depending on the current activity
}

@Override
public void OnError(String e){
 //do something depending on the current activity
})
}
```

So far I have tried multiple methods, the best I could come up with is in the code below, but as I am sure you can tell from the post it did not work but I will leave it here as it might give somebody a better idea of what I am trying to do.

```
ServerRequest mockReq = mock(ServerRequest.class);
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Running first time");
            Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
            ResponseInterface inter = (ResponseInterface) arguments[2];
            Object obj = "Already taken";
            inter.OnSuccess(obj);
            return null;
        }
    }).when(mockReq).InformationRequest(ArgumentMatchers.anyMap(),anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.<ServerInterface>any());
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated as I have no clue what I am doing.

Comment: What is  `RequestDataInterface`. Please edit to post 1/ the code you want to test 2/ the test code (the one you have) and remove everything unrelated.

Comment: Sorry I was messing around with the mock earlier and forgot to revert, I think I have fixed all issues now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else is ever trying to achieve something similar I have figured out how to call the method in the interface sent through the mocked method.
So to start off I created setup method annotated with before (not necessarily needed you can place this just before your test in the same method). Then I began setting up everything needed to achieve my goals, here is the setup required.

```
//class to be mocked
@Mock
ServerRequest mockReq;

@Before
public void setup(){
    //get the activity instance
    Registration reg = mActivityRule.getActivity();
    //make sure the actual method to be mocked does nothing, By default it should do nothing anyway but for some reason  not for me 
    doNothing().when(mockReq).InformationRequest(ArgumentMatchers.anyMap(),anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.<ServerInterface>any());
    //set up an argument catcher
    captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ServerInterface.class);
    //inject the mock into the activity
    reg.serverRequest = mockReq;
}
```

Next up in my test method the mocked method should be called when the submit button is clicked, in which case I verify the mocked method was actually called and capture the data sent to it, then I use the data in what ever manner I wish.

```
 //click the button
 onView(withId(R.id.SubmitBtn)).perform(scrollTo(), click());
 //check to see if method was called then capture the interface
 verify(mockReq).InformationRequest(ArgumentMatchers.anyMap(),anyString(),captor.capture());
  //get the interface
 ServerInterface serverInter = captor.getValue();
 Object obj = "Already taken";
 //make use of the interface
 serverInter.OnSuccess(obj);
```